# publish in bat file

Tags: batch-file, publish

I need to publish my web project , so I do :

```
SET pathMSBuild="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe"  
%pathMSBuild% /p:DeployOnBuild=true /nologo /filelogger   /p:OutputPath="%~dp0% %Output\publish" "%webProjDir%\WEBproj.csproj"
```

the problem is that 10 files are missing in the "bin" folder

What should  I fix?

```
the files :

XMLDesignerData.dll
XMLDesignerData.pdb
XMLDesignerIDRFImage.dll
XMLDesignerIDRFImage.pdb
XMLDesignerParser.dll
XMLDesignerParser.pdb
zlibwapi32.dll
zlibwapi64.dll
Logs (folder)
NLog.confi
```

Comment: can you list those 10 files

Comment: This strange thing that in the last 10 files.

XMLDesignerData.dll

Comment: XMLDesignerData.dll
XMLDesignerData.pdb
 XMLDesignerIDRFImage.dll
XMLDesignerIDRFImage.pdb
XMLDesignerParser.dll
XMLDesignerParser.pdb
zlibwapi32.dll 
zlibwapi64.dll

Comment: Please tell me, is all of this a single line: `%pathMSBuild% /p:DeployOnBuild=true /nologo /filelogger /p:OutputPath="%~dp0% %Output\publish" "%webProjDir%\WEBproj.csproj"` (if yes, please correct it in your question...)

Comment: What value does variable `webProjDir` have? And are you sure the portion `"%~dp0% %Output\publish"` is correct or should it rather be `"%~dp0Output\publish"`?

Comment: I tested two options - the same result

Comment: Ok , i figured it
the dlls are in the:
"%~dp0% %Output\publish
and not in the bin folder

Thanks a lot